# Removing Gnome Software Snap Plugin breaks Gnome Software Storefront on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, software-center

I just removed snapd & the Gnome Software snap plugin and I noticed that it broke the Gnome Software front page, where you can see all the featured and editors app picks etc. See attached screenshot. After running `sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap` the Gnome Software Center should default back to showing applications from the Ubuntu repository and not snap store.

I tried clearing the app-info cache but to no avail.

```
$pkill gnome-software
$sudo rm -r /var/cache/app-info
$sudo appstreamcli refresh --force --verbose
```

Gnome Software terminal output:

> 07:48:46:0226 Gs  enabled plugins: packagekit-url-to-app, ubuntuone, packagekit-local, packagekit-refine-repos, os-release, packagekit-offline,
>   fwupd, packagekit-proxy, packagekit, desktop-categories, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-refresh, systemd-updates, appstream, generic-updates, desktop-menu-path, rewrite-resource, hardcoded-featured, odrs, packagekit-refine, hardcoded-blacklist, modalias, steam, hardcoded-popular, icons, packagekit-history, provenance, key-colors, provenance-license, key-colors-metadata
>   07:48:46:0226 Gs  disabled plugins: shell-extensions, dpkg, dummy, repos, epiphany
>   07:48:46:0971 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
>   07:48:46:0971 Gs  hiding category audio-video featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
>   07:48:47:0303 Gs  hiding category graphics featured applications: found only 1 to show, need at least 9
>   07:48:47:0901 Gs  Only 8 apps for popular list, hiding
>   07:48:50:0791 Gdk gnome-software: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.0.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Gnome Software with snapd and snap plugin:

[image: Before snapd and gnome software snap plugin]

Gnome Software without snapd and snap plugin:

[image: Missing recommended applications from repository]